# Custom button on kendo htmleditor

Tags: html, kendo-ui, editor

Hi I am using kendo htmleditor.

And I want to have a custom button on the Kendo html editor.

I try it like this:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m)
    .Tools(t => t
        .Clear()
        .Bold()
        .Italic()
        .ViewHtml()
        .TableEditing()
        .FontColor()
        .FontName()
        .FontSize()
        .Template: '<button class="k-button" onclick="buttonClick()">originele template</button>',
        .CustomTemplate(c => c.Template("<input id='TransformDropDown' style='float: right; margin-bottom: 5px;'/>"))
    )
    .Encode(false)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float: right;" })
)
```

But that doesn't work.

So how to make a custom button on the kendo html editor?

Thank you

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/editor/custom-tools

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m)
    .Name("editor")
    .Tools(t => t
    .Clear()
    .Bold()
    .Italic()
    .ViewHtml()
    .TableEditing()
    .FontColor()
    .FontName()
    .FontSize()
    .CustomTemplate(c=>c.Template("<button class='k-button' style='margin-right: 10px;' onclick='buttonClick()'>originele template</button><input id='TransformDropDown' style='float: right; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 200px;'/>"))

)
.Encode(false)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float: right;" }))
```